# Action bar Icon not fit like other android icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I'm Making andriod application, every thing is going well, but when I use a large images for action bar , android platform does not fit the size of action bar, the Icon appear very large , so how can set width and heights of icons in action bar in android

Comment: What about use a small image?

Comment: I can't do that as I receive the images from the server and Images uploaded by user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved this problem by making dim files for each density according to android standard, and when receive the images from the server re-size them with the corresponding dim value and then add them to my action bar

Answer (score 6):

I hope you have read [Action Bar Icons](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html) document, because document already contains sizes of icons.

[image]

Anyway, here is the Android [Asset Studio tool](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=example&theme=light) which would help you to generate Action bar icons.

Comment: I know that, but the server is sending me the icons that will be shown in actionbar , and server send a very big images and It make a problem with the actionbar

Comment: @AmiraElsayedIsmail then you can't manage it for multiple screens. Yes you can write a image loading and cropping logic but it won't work for  providing multiple screen support.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you would want to use *large images* in an `Action Bar`

The prescribed sizes for Action Bar icons (API Level 11 and above) are these:

**ldpi(120dpi)** - 18x18 px

**mdpi(160dpi)** - 24x24 px

**hdpi(240dpi)** - 36x36 px

**xhdpi(320dpi)** - 48x48 px

Visit this link for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_action_bar.html

Alternatively, simply use the [Android Asset Studio](http://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/icons-actionbar.html#source.space.trim=1&source.space.pad=0&name=example&theme=light) to create the necessary resources for you. All you have to do there is select the Image you want the Action Bar icons for and it creates them for you in a ZIP file ready to use. This one is quite the time saver.